# Grails: Call a localization message from within another message

Tags: spring, grails, resourcebundle

Coming from Struts/XWorks I was able to do something like this

**Messages.properties**

```
myMessage.invalid.fieldvalue=Invalid input for $'{'getText("{0}")'}'
email.label=Email Address
```

**Application Code**

```
getText("myMessage.invalid.fieldvalue",new String[] {"email.label"})
Output: Invalid input for Email Address
```

So basically the parameter I am passing into a message is actually the code for another message and I want to render them both together.

I can't seem to find a way to do this with Grails/Spring messaging.  Is this possible and if so how?

**EDIT**:
To more clearly show one of the reason I am asking for this take this example.

Lets say I have 5 Domain classes with the property `emailAddress`

To validate for NULL I would have to do this

```
myClass1.emailAddress.nullable=Email Address cannot be NULL
myClass2.emailAddress.nullable=Email Address cannot be NULL
myClass3.emailAddress.nullable=Email Address cannot be NULL
myClass4.emailAddress.nullable=Email Address cannot be NULL
myClass5.emailAddress.nullable=Email Address cannot be NULL
```

What I want to be able to do is simply the messaging by overriding the default validation message as such

```
OLD: default.null.message=Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null

NEW: default.null.message=getMessage({0}) cannot be null
emailAddress=Email Address
```

So now anytime any class has a property called `emailAddress` and it validates as NULL I will get the message `Email Address cannot be null`.  There is no need to have 5 messages that basically say the same exact thing.  If I had another class with the property `emailAddress` then its already handled and I dont have to copy and paste a 6th line.

Anytime I have classes with shared property names, all I have to do is add just add a single line for each property that will be applied to all classes

```
sharedProp1= Shared property 1
sharedProp2= Shared property 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get this done by extending the `MessageSource` and overriding the `resolveArguments` method.

```
class CustomMessageSource extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource {
@Override
protected Object[] resolveArguments(Object[] args, Locale locale) {
    if (args == null) {
        return new Object[0];
    }
    List<Object> resolvedArgs = new ArrayList<Object>(args.length);
    for (Object arg : args) {
        if (arg instanceof MessageSourceResolvable) {
            resolvedArgs.add(getMessage((MessageSourceResolvable) arg, locale));
        }
        else {
            //resolvedArgs.add(arg) **REPLACED THIS LINE
            resolvedArgs.add(getMessage(arg, null, arg, locale));
        }
    }
    return resolvedArgs.toArray(new Object[resolvedArgs.size()]);
}
}
```

I replaced a single line within the loop that evaluates your message arguments.  I basically take the argument and see if its a key to another message.  If yes, then replace the argument with that message, if no then continue as normal to use the argument

Make sure to map the new messageSource in your `resources.groovy` file

```
beans = {
    messageSource(groovyUtils.CustomMessageSource) {
        basenames = "messages"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When in a controller, call `message` for the param you want to internationalize and store that in a local variable.
Then call `message` for the full message and add your local variable, with the internationalized param value, as a param to that message.

```
def emailLabel = message(code: "email.label")
def fullMessage = message(code: 'myMessage.invalid.fieldvalue', args: [emailLabel])
```

Your messages.properties would contain something like

```
myMessage.invalid.fieldvalue=Invalid input for {0}
email.label=Email Address
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately I need it to work the way I explained in the post.  I cannot store the `email.label` message in another variable to pass as an argument.  This is merely a simplified example of some of the more complex things I need to use this for.

Comment: This is the correct answer. You will need to describe why this is not enough if you want more help

Comment: @droggo I would say its not the correct answer.  My question specifically asked about calling a message from within another message, not how to pass a parameter into a message.

Comment: @RaymondHolguin In that case you should be overriding MessageSource methods :)

Comment: @VinayPrajapati I added an example of something I am trying to accomplish.  Perhaps that will show why this answer doesn't fit what I need and hopefully give you the info needed to point me in the right direction.